# Is it normal to have a lot of records in Memached with Laravel?

Tags: session, laravel-4, memcached

I have an instance of Laravel up and running with a load balancer in place. We've setup memcached (two server nodes) to handle session management. So far the site is running fine in our test environment. The site largely ties into a web based API, so we only store a few values (other than user authentication data) in a user's session to work with the site.

After a short amount of usage by one or two users, there are about 3000 items in the cache. I don't have full access to the nodes, so I don't know exactly what the items are. However we don't appear to be maxing out the nodes with memory and the application functionality is good.

Is this to be expected? I understand that the cache management will clear out old records over time as they expire, so these could just be "remnant" data records, but this is my first time working with memcached so I want to verify that this is normal behavior.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using Memcached for the API as well? Unfortunately you have to explicitly set the session driver for the API to 'array' in order to make it stateless. Maybe you think the API is stateless and instead it keeps creating sessions because it expects a session id that you're never sending back...

Comment: No, the API is a different system altogether and the Laravel site is more or less a "user shell" to access these commands. I added some debug logging messages and it doesn't appear that we're doing an inordinate amount of session push commands, which makes me think the session storage/retrieval is working. Our server admin indicated that the activity/storage levels seems to top off after a few hours of coming online, so maybe there is just some "on boarding" that needed to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite normal for any caching solution to rack up a number of items. Especially for lots of small objects it's often more efficient for a cache to keep them beyond their expiry (but no longer serve them) and then clear them out in a big sweep periodically. 
*"Remnant records"* pretty much describes it.

As long as your application performs as expected, I wouldn't worry. You should worry when you get a lot of cache misses for objects that were supposed to be in cache but kicked out before expiry due to lack of memory to store them all.

Comment: Well, that's quite the point! If you, as a developer, are not in full control of what's being stored, you may eventually get cache misses. The OP says they "only store a few values" for each authenticated session. Let's say "a few" is 10; to reach 3000 items in cache you still need 300 sessions, which would take weeks to pile up if only "one or two users" are testing. Something we're not aware of is clearly going on; the point is, better to know in advance if it's danger or not!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

It is normal to have lots of records in Memcache. But you need to have proper session management. 
Store small amount of values per session. (Data which is required most of the API's, Like user access token)

**Cache expiration**

The biggest challenge when using Memcache is avoiding cache staleness while still writing clean code. Most developers store data to Memcache and delete or update data when it changes. This strategy can get messy very quickly – Memcache code becomes riddled throughout an application. Rails’ Sweepers can help with this problem, but other languages and frameworks don’t have similar alternatives.

One simple strategy to avoid code complexity is to write data to Memcache with an expiration. Data with an expiration will automatically expire when the expiration is reached. Most applications can benefit from time-based cache expiration with infrequently changing content such as static assets, headers, footers, blog posts, etc.

**List management**

A simple list stored in Memcache can be useful for maintaining denormalized relationships.

**For example** An e-commerce website may want to store a small table of recent purchases. Rather than keeping a serialized list in Memcache and recalculating it when a new purchase is made, append and prepend can be used to store denormalized data, avoiding a database query.

**Note** - Memcache only supports a max value size of 1 MB. Be careful creating lists that may grow larger in size than the maximum allowed value size

Also Check these links-
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/memcache

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/ha-memcached-faq.html

http://symas.com/mdb/memcache/